# ArgumentError: Python argument types in rdkit.Chem.rdMolDescriptors.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(NoneType, int) did not match C++ signature

Tags: python, rdkit

So I'm working with RDKit and Python to convert SMILES strings to ECFP4 fingerprints, and my code is as shown below. I got an error, but I have also checked with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67451032/argumenterror-rdkit-chem-rdmoldescriptors-getmorganfingerprintasbitvectmol-in) over here but I seem to have the correct code? But why am I still getting an error?

Is there an alternative way to code this?

```
bits = 1024
PandasTools.AddMoleculeColumnToFrame(data, smilesCol='SMILES')
data_ECFP4 = [AllChem.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(x, 3, nBits = bits) for x in data['ROMol']]
data_ecfp4_lists = [list(l) for l in data_ECFP4]
ecfp4_name = [f'B{i+1}' for i in range(1024)]
data_ecfp4_df = pd.DataFrame(data_ecfp4_lists, index = data.TARGET, columns = ecfp4_name)
```

The error I got is:

> ArgumentError: Python argument types in rdkit.Chem.rdMolDescriptors.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(NoneType, int)
> did not match C++ signature: GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(class RDKit::ROMol mol, int radius, unsigned int nBits=2048, class boost::python::api::object invariants=[], class boost::python::api::object fromAtoms=[], bool useChirality=False, bool useBondTypes=True, bool useFeatures=False, class boost::python::api::object bitInfo=None, bool includeRedundantEnvironments=False)

Comment: Did you checked if there `None` in `data['ROMol']`?

Comment: I didn't. Let me check that first!

Comment: I did check and there was several `None` values in the `ROMol` column. I removed them and reran the code, but I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: I tried all other ways and it did not work. I guess it's an error with the library? I used the KNIME software instead to do the conversion!

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that your list contains irregular values, such as 'None', nan, or just  empty items. In your code the 'x' should correspond to a single string.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import PandasTools
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
PandasTools.AddMoleculeColumnToFrame(df, "SMILES")
df = df[~df['ROMol'].isnull()]
df.to_csv('new_file.csv')
```

Comment: I fixed the similar error using the 'new_file.csv' I got from the above code.